# How can I find out why a character is highlighted in Vim?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Vim has a tonne of highlighting built in, and plug-ins add more. Highlighting is applied for various reasons, including code syntax, spelling, indenting, search, coding errors and standards, and so on. Because there is limited options for highlighting, there are a few highlights that look the same - in particular, code errors, and spelling mistakes are both underlined red (in my colourscheme).

Is there any way of asking vim "What highlighting rules are being applied to the character under the cursor?"

Answer (score 3):

To find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from; (the last lines of) `:scriptnames` may help.